# Which is better to use DynamoDB filter expression or filter in code?

Tags: database, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

In our application, we have to filter some data. we are using Dynamo DB. In our team, we have a different opinion to use filter expression at dynamo or application level. I want to know what has been following in the industry. Please let me know if you know about some good blogs?

Consider the scenario, we have to deal-template in the active state which can be deactivated by the user. In the get list call, we want to send only active templates.

**Dynamo:**

```
filterCondition := expression.Name(activeColumn).Equal(expression.Value(true))
```

**Application:**

```
List<DealTemplate> templates = getTemplate()
for templaes := range templates {
    if template.isActive {
        // process
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

May be getting close to the line regarding questions with opinion based answers..

But the best solution is to structure your data so you don't have to filter anything out at all.  Use either a Local Secondary Index (LSI - no extra cost) or a Global Secondary Index (GSI - extra cost)

This way you don't have to pay to read data that gets thrown away.

Otherwise use a filter expression. You still have to pay to read the data, but you don't have to pay to transfer it back; in real $$ if out of AWS and in overhead regardless.